# Laravel 5.8 foreign relation on same table

Tags: sql, laravel, migration

Heyho,

I am trying to create a foreign relation on the same table using Laravel 5.8 migrations. The code for the table looks like this:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('shop_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('shop_parent_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('synctime');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('shop_parent_id')->references('shop_id')->on('categories');
    });
```

As you can see, I am already making sure, that both columns have the same datatype, but I still get the good old:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `mydatabase`.`categories` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `categories` add constraint `categories_shop_parent_id_foreign` foreign key (`shop_parent_id`) references `categories` (`shop_id`))
```

Can anyone point out my mistake here please? Would be cool if the mistake would not be the self-reference... ;)

Greetings

Comment: can you first make id a primary key

Answer (score 1):

Could you try

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned()->unique();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('shop_id')->unsigned();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('shop_parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('synctime');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->primary(['id']);
});

Schema::table('categories', function($table) {
    $table->foreign('shop_parent_id')->references('shop_id')
              ->on('categories'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This method will not work**, so I think my second suggestion with pivot table is the only option there. Or you can define the relation only in Laravel model, because it will work anyway.

**Original answer:**

I think you should break it to two schema queries:

```php
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('shop_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('shop_parent_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('synctime');
        $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('categories', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('shop_parent_id')->references('shop_id')->on('categories');
});
```

or create a pivot table where you'll store the relationship, which I think might be a better approach, because then you're not limited to one parent category per children.

Comment: Hello,
Well - breaking it down results in the same error and a pivot-table is useless here, since the shop where I got the data from only has this one column. So there will be no more parents than one. I could only use "parent_id" but then I would have to remember that it comes from the shop and not from myself.

Comment: I just completely forgot that foreign key is a key used to link two tables together. So it won't work. However, you can define relation in Laravel model and it will work anyway, if you're doing it because of that.

Comment: Damned - I think I have to... But let's wait a bit, maybe someone has another idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

I always build my relationships into the same method as the creation in my migrations. I don't think Silencesys's answer is correct.

I actually think a bigger part of the issue is your implementation.

With foreign keys referencing a primary key on the same table, a lot of SQL functionality breaks. (Cascade for example).

You might be better off figuring out how to divide whatever you're doing into two different models instead.

---

The only solution I can really come up with here that will leave your current structure relatively intact would be to create a "pivot table" that essentially just pivots the same table together.

shop_id | shop_parent_id

2            |                 1

3           |                4

Comment: Hello - Well I guess the point is, that I am NOT referencing a primary key, but a regular-column...

Comment: Try specifying the cascade rules explicitly? $table->foreign('shop_parent_id')->references('shop_id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('restrict');